# Выравнивание по вертикали flexbox

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

```css
.header {
  margin: 60px 0;
}

.header__form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/childoflight/images/1/19/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_Steam.png/revision/latest?cb=20160320085501&path-prefix=ru" alt="Logo" class="header__logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <form action="" class="header__form">
          <input type="search" class="header__search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Почему не работает вертикальное выравнивание?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте обернуть ваши блоки в flex контейнер так:

```css
.header {
  margin: 60px 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="row flex-container">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/childoflight/images/1/19/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_Steam.png/revision/latest?cb=20160320085501&path-prefix=ru" alt="Logo" class="header__logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <form action="" class="header__form">
                    <input type="search" class="header__search">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Так же рекомендую освежить **[теорию по flex](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)**

Comment: Спасибо, не додумался)